# Limit of 50 =importData functions per sheet - workaround?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

In a sheet of mine I used 50 importData functions to shorten links via bit.ly automatically. Unfortunately, there is a limit of 50 functions per sheet which doesn't allow me to add more functions.

I don't want to open up more and more sheets, because that would be messy long term. Do you have recommendations for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) and put this to get the contents of your url:

```
  var info = UrlFetchApp.fetch("yourURL");
```

Process the info and return it.

You might need to use

```
Utilities.sleep(1000);
```

...between the calls in order to get a value for every cell.